# How to test a struct that calls its own method?

Tags: unit-testing, go, mocking

I have a struct:

```
type foo struct {
    bar mockableInterface // some interface that I can mock
}

func (f *foo) DoSmth1() []interface{} {
    return f.bar.Bar()
}

func (f *foo) DoSmth2() []interface{} {
    res := f.DoSmth1()
    //some code to test
}
```

Here I have no problem with mocking `bar` and testing `DoSmth1()`. But it's not obvious how to test `DoSmth2()`.
Should I rewrite this method to make it testable or rewrite tests somehow?

Comment: Test `DoSmth2` normally. Mocks are for dependencies, not internal method calls.

Comment: What does "normally" mean?)

Comment: @mkopriva it's the only variant I see at the moment. But it seems to me that code that tests `DoSmth2()` shouldn't depend on changes in DoSmth1()

Comment: They're methods of the same type. A method can't avoid a dependency on its receiver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@mkopriva recommended just to mock `Bar()` call in `DoSmth2()` test. But in this case I would rewrite tests for all method that calls `DoSmth1()` every time it changes. So I've come to the following solution. We can encapsulate this mock logic in one method:

```
func (s *TestSuite) ExpectDoSmth1(times int, in, out []interface{}) {
    s.barMock.Expect().Bar(in...).Times(times).Return(out...)
}
```

This way we can change only this method if `DoSmth1()` implementation changes, till its API stays the same